# Something like rank() in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can I write a query in SQL Server such as `rank()` but a bit different calculate.

For example rank is:

```
rankNumber uniqeId
1             160 
2             159
3             158
4             157
5             156
5             156
7             152
8             151
8             151
10            150
```

I need the result like these:

```
rankNumber uniqeId
1           160
2           159
3           158
4           157
5           156
5           156
6           152
7           151
7           151
8           150
```

How can I do this? Is there such a function in SQL Server?

Comment: just use `DENSE_RANK` instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY TotCnt DESC) AS TopCustomers, CustomerID, TotCnt

FROM (SELECT CustomerID, COUNT(*) AS TotCnt

FROM Orders Group BY CustomerID) AS Cust
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the `DENSE_RANK` comment, the full query is short and sweet:

```
SELECT
  DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY uniqueId DESC) AS rankNumber,
  uniqueId
FROM myTable
ORDER BY rankNumber
```

There's a SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/54406/1)